# Reading data word by word

Tags: c

I have a list of data, and I am trying to store the chars in one array of ints and the decimals in an array of doubles. The problem is: How do you do this without reading the whole line? I am thinking that maybe asking if there is a space, to stop reading. But how would I do this while taking into account that there are multiple lines? Here is the data:

```
A 0.08030130328545595500
B 0.01404566680148545800
C 0.02309245337888202900
D 0.04680329046987134100
E 0.12475974957130967000
F 0.02262448732647651800
G 0.02092142515718645500
H 0.06495870199587520900
I 0.06832638626586488900
J 0.00118328558965393900
K 0.00796545073487383260
L 0.03678714564106335500
M 0.02553256208071077300
N 0.07071134182580297900
O 0.07759211410349403600
P 0.01653257210855475400
Q 0.00111309068179311220
R 0.06200383063640040700
S 0.06269909448568859700
T 0.09005003894146078300
U 0.02792921679195900500
V 0.00865068674018190480
W 0.02356209073861756000
X 0.00115988728703366340
Y 0.02033479628434954300
Z 0.00035933107595423293
```

Comment: Have you tried any code? Have you done a search?

Comment: What's the problem with reading the whole line? Are you going to use `%s` or `%c` to read the character (assuming you use `scanf()`)? Assuming you use `%c` to read the character into a character before assigning to the array of `int`, the trick is to know that `%c` does not skip white space, such as the newline left behind after the number is read, so you need to let `scanf()` know to skip space with `" %c…"` (a space before the `%c`). The rest is trivial. Don't forget to test the return value from `scanf()`; it will be 2 if everything is OK and something else (0, 1, EOF) if there's a problem.

Comment: Are you reading from a file or stdin?

Comment: @kaylum Yes, I tried `lettersone[ch] = fgetc(fp);
            fgets(freqone[ch], 22, fp);` but no luck, I just am unsure how to store the numbers in an array. I am trying to make array freqone store all of the decimals.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int ch[32] = {0};
    double num[32];
    char word[32];
    int i = 0, n, flipflop = 0;

    while(1 == scanf("%31s", word)){//read word by word
        if(flipflop){
            num[i++] = atof(word);
        } else {
            if(*word && !word[1]){//a character
                ch[i] = *word;
            }
        }
        flipflop = !flipflop;
    }
    n = i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){//test print
        printf("%c %.20f\n", ch[i], num[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```